# Globally invariant subalgebras of $ K \otimes_F K $.

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory, tensor-products

I'm working through the last exercise in Tignol's *Galois' theory of algebraic equations*, which is about an unusual proof of the Galois correspondence. The setup and the part of the question I'm struggling with are excerpted below.

> Let $ K/F $ be a Galois extension of fields with Galois group $G$ and let $ \mathcal{F}(G,K) $ be the $K$-vector space of all maps from $G$ to $K$.
>
> (a) Show that there is a well-defined $F$-linear map
>     \begin{equation*}
>     \varphi: K \otimes_{F} K \to \mathcal{F}(G,K)
>   \end{equation*}
>     such that $ \varphi( a \otimes b )(\sigma) = \sigma(a)b $ for $a,b \in K $.

As far as I can see, this is a consequence $\sigma \in G$ fixing $F$, so $\psi(a,b,\sigma)=\sigma(a)b$ is $F$-bilinear, and of the universal property of the tensor product.

> (b) Consider $ K \otimes_{F} K $ as a vector space over $K$ by $ ( a \otimes b ) \cdot k = a \otimes bk $. Show that $ \varphi $ is $K$-linear and bijective.

$K$-linear is easy enough, given this definition of the scalar multiplication. Bijective follows by results about the rank of the matrix of the map with respect to the bases $(e_j \otimes 1)_{1 \leq j \leq n}$ and $f_k:\sigma_i \mapsto \delta_{ik}$, which are proved in the text and the previous question, but I don't think this part is relevant beyond the definitions.

> (d) Let $G$ act on $K \otimes K $ by $\sigma(a \otimes b) = a \otimes \sigma(b) $. [...]
>
> (e) Show that a $K$-subalgebra of $K \otimes K $ is globally invariant under the action of $G$ defined in (d) if and only if it has the form $ L \otimes_{F} K $ for some subfield $L$ of $K$ containing $F$.
>
> [Hint: for any $K$-subalgebra $A$ of $K \otimes K$, define $ L = \{ x \in K \mid x \otimes 1 \in A \} $. Show that every $ \sum_{i=1}^{r} a_{i} \otimes b_{i} \in A $ is in $ L \otimes K $ by induction on the number $r$ of terms.]

This is the part I'm stuck on. I seem to be able to do this, but I don't seem to have used the global invariance under $G$, which is odd, so maybe I have misunderstood the question. Facts that I think I know:

- We need to equip $K \otimes K$ (presumably this is still $K \otimes_F K $) with a bilinear product to turn it from a $K$-vector space into a $K$-algebra. The obvious way to do this is to set $(a \otimes b) \cdot (c \otimes d) = (ac) \otimes (bd)$ and extend linearly. Since the book says nothing about this, presumably it's simple, and this seems the simplest way to me.
- $K \otimes K$ the $K$-algebra is composed of elements of the form
  $$ \sum_{i=1}^r a_i \otimes b_i, \qquad r \geq 1, a_i,b_i \in K. $$
  We have $F$-linearity in both arguments of $a \otimes b$ and $K$-linearity in the second by the definition of $K \otimes K$ as a $K$-vector space in (b), and the product mentioned in the previous point that turns $K \otimes K$ into a $K$-algebra.
- Now let $A$ be a $K$-subalgebra of $K \otimes K$. This means that $K$-linear combinations of elements of $A$ are in $A$, and the product of two elements of $A$ is in $A$. If in addition $A$ is globally invariant, $G(A) \subseteq A$.
- We want to show that ($A$ is a $K$-subalgebra that is is globally invariant under the action of $G$) $\iff$ ($A = L \otimes_F K$ where $L$ is a subfield of $K$ and contains $F$)

So suppose first that we have $L\otimes_F K$ where $L$ is a subfield of $K$ and contains $F$. We want to show that this is a subalgebra of $K \otimes K$ and that it is globally invariant under the action of $G$.

Check it's a subalgebra: the elements of $L \otimes K$ are all of the form $\sum_{i=1}^r c_i \otimes b_i$ with $r \geq 1$, $c_i \in L$ and $b_i \in K$. Obviously a $K$-linear combination of these is still in $L \otimes K $ since it is of the same form. Equally, $(c \otimes b) \cdot (c' \otimes b') = (cc') \otimes (bb')$ is in $L \otimes K$, so bilinearity and induction give that $L \otimes F$ is a $K$-subalgebra.

Check it's invariant under the action of $G$: for $\sigma \in G$, the definition in (d) gives $\sigma \left( \sum_{i=1}^r c_i \otimes b_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^r c_i \otimes \sigma(b_i) $ (assuming the action extends linearly to elements of higher rank—what else could it do?), and $\sigma(b_i) \in K$, so we get $\impliedby$. Fine.

---

---

Now the other direction. Suppose that $A$ is a subalgebra. Define $L$ as in the Hint.

1. First we show that $L$ is an $F$-vector space (and hence an abelian group). Suppose that $x,y \in L$. Then $x \otimes 1, y \otimes 1 \in A$ by definition. Then if $a,b \in F$, $ (ax+by) \otimes 1 = a(x \otimes 1) + b(y \otimes 1) \in A $ since elements of $K \otimes K$ are $F$-linear in the first argument and $A$ is an $F$-vector space. Hence $ax+by \in L$ and so $L$ is an $F$-vector space.
2. Next we show $L$ is closed under products. With $x,y$ as before, $ (xy) \otimes 1 = (x \otimes 1) \cdot (y \otimes 1) \in A$ by the definition of the product and $A$'s being a subalgebra, so $L$ is indeed closed under products.
3. Now we show $F \subseteq L$. Let $x \in L$. Then $x^k \in L$ for $k \geq 0$, and the usual linear algebra implies that there is a monic irreducible polynomial $p(X) = X^m + p_{m-1}X^{m-1} + \dotsc + p_0 \in F[X]$ of degree $m \leq [K:F]$ so that $p(x)=0$. Since it is irreducible, $p(0) = p_0 \neq 0$, and since $p(x) \neq 0$, $p_0 = -x^m-p_{m-1}x^{m-1}- \dotsb -p_1 x $. $L$ is an $F$-vector space, and the right-hand side is an $F$-linear combination of elements of $L$, so $p_0 \in F \cap L$. But for any $q \in F$, $qp_0^{-1} \in F$, so $qp_0^{-1}p_0 = q \in L$ for any $q \in F$. Hence $F \subseteq L$.
4. Lastly we need to show $x^{-1} \in L$. Suppose again that $x \in L$ with minimal polynomial $p$, then we have $x^{-1} = -p_0^{-1} (x^{m-1} + p_{m-1}x^{m-2} + \dotsb + p_1) \in L $ by a similar argument to before.

Therefore $L$ is a subfield of $K$ that contains $F$.

---

We now need to show that $A = L \otimes K $. Proceed as the Hint suggests: let us start with elements of the form $a \otimes b \in A$. Then $A$ is a $K$-vector space, so $ A \ni (a \otimes b) \cdot (b^{-1}) = a \otimes 1$, so $a \in L$ and hence $a \otimes b \in L \otimes K$.

Now suppose that every member of $A$ of the form $\sum_{i=1}^r a_i \otimes b_i$ is in $L \otimes K$, and consider $ \sum_{i=1}^{r+1} a_i \otimes b_i $. But this is the sum of two terms: $ \sum_{i=1}^{r} a_i \otimes b_i \in L \otimes K $ by the induction hypothesis, and $a_{r+1} \otimes b_{r+1} \in A$ since it is the difference of two elements of $A$, which lies in $L \otimes K$  by the basis case. Hence $\sum_{i=1}^{r+1} a_i \otimes b_i$ is the sum of two elements of $L \otimes K$ and so itself lies in $L \otimes K$.

Hence every element of $A$ lies in $L \otimes K$, so $A \subseteq L \otimes K$. Lastly, we want to show that $L \otimes K \subseteq A$, which follows because every element of $L \otimes K$ can be written as a $K$-linear combination of elements of the form $a \otimes 1 \in L \otimes K$.

---

So that would seem to be it. But I haven't used anything about $G$ at all in the $\implies$ proof! So this seems to imply that *all* $K$-subalgebras of $K \otimes_F K $ are globally invariant under this $G$-action. But apparently this is not the case, given that the next part of the question involves showing that subalgebras of $\mathcal{F}(G,K)$ (which are presumably in bijection with those of $K \otimes_F K$ by (a) and (b)) are in bijection with partitions of $G$, and are globally $G$-invariant precisely when they correspond to a partition of $G$ into cosets of a subgroup, and obviously not all partitions of $G$ are such.

Can someone point out my error?

Comment: a) is not a consequence of the universal property of the tensor product. Try computing $K \otimes_F K$ for some extensions which are not Galois.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan okay, perhaps I should be more explicit in what I was thinking. I see I do also need that $\sigma \in G$ fixes the elements of $F$ in order for the function to be $F$-linear, so the function $K \times K \times G \to K$ defined by $\psi(a,b,\sigma) = \sigma(a)b$ is then $F$-bilinear and *then* the universal property of the tensor product says that this factors into a function $ K \otimes_F K \times G \to K$ in a well-defined/unique way. Is that what you were getting at?

Comment: Ah, never mind, you're fine, I slightly misinterpreted what would happen in the non-Galois case (which is that this map fails to be injective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your induction step does not work. By the induction hypothesis, you only know that every element of the form $\sum_{i=1}^r a_i \otimes b_i$ *which is in $A$* is also in $L\otimes K$. In general, you can't conclude from  $\sum_{i=1}^{r+1} a_i \otimes b_i \in A$ that $\sum_{i=1}^r a_i \otimes b_i \in A$, so the induction hypothesis does not apply.

I think it's instructive to give a concrete example to show where it goes wrong:

Let $F=\Bbb Q$ and $K=\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt{2})$, then a $K$-basis of $K\otimes_F K$  (with respect to the action of $K$ as in the OP) is given by $(1\otimes1,i\otimes1,\sqrt{2}\otimes 1, i\sqrt{2}\otimes 1)$.

Consider the element $$\alpha=2 i\otimes i - \sqrt{2} \otimes \sqrt{2} - i\sqrt{2}\otimes i\sqrt{2}\in K\otimes_F K$$ A simple computation shows that $\alpha^2=12\otimes 1 +4\alpha$, so the $K$-subvector space spanned by $1\otimes 1$ and $\alpha$ is closed under multiplication, thus it is a subalgebra, which I will call $A$. It's not difficult to compute that $L=\Bbb Q$ in this case. If we try to apply the induction step to $\alpha$, we need to have that $2i\otimes i -\sqrt{2}\otimes\sqrt{2} \in A$, but this element is not a linear combination of $\alpha$ and $1\otimes 1$.